# Is using display: none the proper way to hide elements in a theme?

Tags: theme-development

I'm trying to customize a purchased theme and I need to hide a bunch of default elements. Removing these elements is not natively supported by the themes options.

I've done some research on removing elements and it looks like just using `display: none;` is recommended often. Is this the best way to remove elements?

I haven't worked with Wordpress too much in the past so my gut reaction was to just remove those elements in the template files.

I tried to find a location in the these files where I could remove them but it seems like these features are very "baked in" and would require a lot of work just to remove a few elements. Is this the right way to go?

Comment: not sure how this question is wordpress specific. In the min it is too broad as it is obviosly depends on context

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is first make sure you're using a Child Theme:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Then you should be able to copy over the template file being used in the parent theme, to your child theme's directory, and customize from the child theme directory as you want.  WordPress should automatically load the file from your child theme if it exists (assuming the template file is a standard WordPress file)

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png

Using `display: none;` is a very common CSS method of hiding elements, but that also means that the page size, load time, etc, will include those elements, any backend calls, etc.

Your theme developer may have integrated some filters as well which you may be able to use to prevent specific items from being output, your best bet is to contact them and ask and pretty much all premium themes come with some type of support.